# Every Haar measure is a multiple of the counting measure.

Tags: measure-theory, haar-measure

I was asked to prove the following:

> Let $G$ be a group, equipped with the discrete topology.
> A Haar measure on $G$ is a measure $\mathcal{P}(G) \rightarrow [0, \infty]$
> such that:
> $$\mu(K) < \infty$$ for all compact sets K
> and $$\mu(gU) = \mu(U) \; \forall g \in G \; \forall U \subset G$$
> Then $\mu = a*z$ where $z$ is the counting measure and $a \in \mathbb{R}_0^+$

The compact sets are all finite sets and therefore this is not too difficult to show if the measure for finite sets is non zero.

But what about the following measures on $\mathbb{R}$ as a group with addition and the discrete topology
$$\mu(U) = 0 \; \forall U \subset \mathbb{R}$$
$$\mu(U) = 0 \text{ if U is countable else } \mu(U)=\infty  $$
They both seem to be Haar measures to me, but they cant both be a multiple of the counting measure. Am I missing something?

Comment: Haar measures must be inner and outer regular, and yours isn't inner regular.

Comment: But thats the definition I was given in my exercise. So are you saying that with the given definition is not complete?

Comment: I'm reading from wikipedia. I don't know about your exercise, I'm not attending your course.

Comment: I just wanted to ask if I made a mistake in my argument somewhere before I tell my prof that the task can't actually be solved completely. That's why included the definition I got.

Comment: You are both right.  Without the assumption of "inner regular",  the OP has a counterexample to the proposed result.  Of course the first measure (zero everywhere) is a scalar multiple of counting measure, where the scalar is $0$.  But the second measure is not a scalar multiple of counting measure.

Comment: How do you define "countable" ?  (I always use it to mean countably infinite, i.e., bijective with aleph_0. But some people use the word to mean "either countably infinite or finite".)

Comment: For "countable" see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Countable_set